# How can I use Emacs ESS mode with R markdown?

Tags: r, emacs, ess, r-markdown

Is there a way to configure Emacs so that it recognizes (and allows execution of) R code chunks within R markdown (.Rmd) files similar to the way it recognizes code chunks in .Rnw (Sweave) or .org (org-mode) files?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The other answers are rather outdated, and `polymode` now provides a specialized package for working with `.Rmd` files. Simply use the `poly-R` package [from MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/poly-R) which has its [source here on Github.](https://github.com/polymode/poly-R)

The following may be added to your `init.el` or where-ever you use `use-package`:

```
(use-package poly-R
  :ensure t
  :pin melpa-stable)
```

For a more detailed use-case involving modifying the default keymaps see [this configuration](https://dotdoom.rgoswami.me/config.html#org17909a2). The [documentation describes](https://polymode.github.io/usage/) the default keymaps.

Comment: This worked.  I installed the `ess` and `poly-R` packages with MELPA and (for my Mac) I needed to modify my emacs `exec-path` to make it all work

Answer (score 37):

[polymode](https://github.com/vitoshka/polymode) is being developed which does/will allow you to write markdown with R chunks (for processing with `knitr`).

Instructions for setting up polymode+rmarkdown are in the [README](https://github.com/vspinu/polymode/blob/master/readme.md)

It is not yet done, but is progressing.  See also this discussion on the ess-help mailing list ([gmane archive](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.ess.general/6994)|[mailing list archive](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/ess-help/2013-March/008755.html))

---

Update: polymode has been released on MELPA, simplifying the installation process by using emacs' existing package mechanism. See the [announcement on the ESS mailing list here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/ess-help/2014-May/009926.html).

Answer (score 23):

Download the zip for `polymode` from [github.com/vitoshka/polymode](https://github.com/vitoshka/polymode.git) or, if you are a "git guy", you might use:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/vitoshka/polymode.git
```

Add this function to your Emacs init file:

```lisp
(defun rmd-mode ()
  "ESS Markdown mode for rmd files"
  (interactive)
  (setq load-path 
    (append (list "path/to/polymode/" "path/to/polymode/modes/")
        load-path))
  (require 'poly-R)
  (require 'poly-markdown)     
  (poly-markdown+r-mode))
```

Now, if you already have ESS installed, just open your rmd file and type <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>`rmd-mode` and watch the beauty of Emacs.

### Update for MELPA users

`polymode` from MELPA uses a *flat* file structure. When you install from an Emacs repository via `M-x list-packages` or like facilities, you get your package files straight where they ought to, i.e.: `(expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa")`, therefore do comment the above `load-path` code:

```lisp
;;  (setq load-path 
;;      (append (list "path/to/polymode/" "path/to/polymode/modes/")
;;          load-path))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this code. I want only mention that this works only if markdown-mode.el is in the `"path/to/"` folder (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022431/emacs-polymode-gives-error-when-opening-file)).

Comment: when I download `polymode` from MELPA it goes into this path on my windows machine `c:/emacs/.emacs.d/elpa/polymode-20150105.931/` but I don't see the `modes` folder in that! any idea? can you refere to windows in your answer, very much appreciate that.

Comment: how do I execute R code with this setup? I don't see ESS menu for switching between Rmd and R buffer, executing code, etc

Comment: @pavopax: ESS needs a separate setup. Once done, `M-x R` starts R and inside a chunk `C-c C-z` switches to R console.

Comment: the key is "inside R chunk" not just anywhere in buffer. thanks!

Comment: Polymode from git uses a flat structure too.