# Emacs polymode gives error when opening file

Tags: emacs, knitr, ess

I downloaded the polymode zip-file [from GitHub](https://github.com/vspinu/polymode), open the zip-file which gives a folder named *polymode-master* . I renamed the folder to *polymode* and put it on my .emacs.d folder. Then I inserted the following lines into my .emacs file:

```
;; Polymode
(setq load-path
      (append '("~/.emacs.d/polymode/" "~/.emacs.d/polymode/modes")
          load-path))

(require 'poly-R)
(require 'poly-markdown)
```

When I open a file with emacs it gives me the following error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `c:/Users/ab/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, markdown-mode

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Any idea what I did wrong?
Thanks for help.

PS:
Windows 7
GNU Emacs 24.3.1
ESS

Comment: Do you have `markdown-mode` installed?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for answer. I don't think so. I have to find out how to find out if a package is installed.

Comment: Try `(require 'markdown-mode nil t)`. If it gives `markdown-mode` you have it. If it gives `nil` you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`polymode` [depends on `markdown-mode` for its Markdown support](https://github.com/vspinu/polymode/blob/master/modes/poly-markdown.el#L33), and it doesn't look like you have it installed.

Since you're using Emacs 24, which has `package.el` built-in, I strongly recommend installing it [via MELPA stable](http://stable.melpa.org/#/markdown-mode) (also available in [regular MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/markdown-mode) and [Marmalade](https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/markdown-mode)), but if you're still installing packages manually you can find it [on its website](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/).

Comment: Thank you very much. Together with the info from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172345/how-can-i-use-emacs-ess-mode-with-r-markdown/23326318#23326318) I could arrange the highlighting of markdown.